# How can I enable both http and https endpoint?

Tags: c#, wcf, app-config

I am accessing the service which has is setup in the WAS server that

allows both http and https endpoint access. How can I modify same in my app.config file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>    
<add key="WebServiceUrl1" value="http://vissvc-  test.e.corpintra.net/VisSvcNative/VisService"/>
<add key="LogoutUrl" value="http://login.e.corpintra.net/internal/logout"/>
</appSettings>
<system.net>
<defaultProxy >
  <proxy autoDetect ="True" />
</defaultProxy>
</system.net> 
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>      
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="SoapBinding">  
      <customTextMessageEncoding encoding="UTF-8" messageVersion="Soap11" />  
      <httpTransport/>          
    </binding>       
  </customBinding>      
</bindings>        
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://vissvc-test.e.corpintra.net/VisSvcNative/VisService"
            binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="SoapBinding"                contract="ServiceReference1.VisServicePortType" name="VisService" behaviorConfiguration="behavior" />      
               </client>
 </system.serviceModel>
 </configuration>
```

I am using .net c# 4.0

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: The service your are consuming is exposing HTTP?

Comment: @MilanRaval- It has both http and https, https://vissvc-int.e.corpintra.net/VisSvcNative/VisService. I want to include three endpoint one endpoint with http and two with https. Yes the one configured in the app.config is HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add `<httpsTransport>` under `<httpTransport>` as well.

Take a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731818.aspx) for more information on the `<httpsTransport>` tag.

EDIT: What I mean is there should be another binding configuration for the `<httpsTransport>`, for example:

```
<bindings>      
  <customBinding>
     <binding name="SoapBinding">
        <httpTransport />
     </binding>
     <binding name="HttpsSoapBinding">
        <httpsTransport />
     </binding>     
  </customBinding>      
</bindings>
```

Also note that these binding names have to match that on the server configuration.

Comment: it says the binding name already exists.<customBinding>
        <binding name="SoapBinding">
          <customTextMessageEncoding encoding="UTF-8" messageVersion="Soap11" />
          <httpTransport/>          
        </binding>
        <binding name="SoapBinding">
          <httpsTransport/>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>

Comment: You have to use a different name on the second binding configuration for httpsTransport. You have used the name "Soapbinding" for both.

Comment: @HOKBONG- Okay but is that should be predefined by the service ?